# LEFT JOIN if a condition is met otherwise continue to select others

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I have looked around for something that would fit what I'm looking for. I am by no means close to a SQL expert so I'm asking here. I want to grab a and b regardless of if c exists, but if c does exist LEFT JOIN it to the return. Here is the statement I am working with at the moment:

```
SELECT a.display_name, a.first_name, a.last_name, a.profile_image, a.tagline,
       a.bragging_rights, a.about_me, b.type AS post_type, b.title AS post_title,
       b.published AS post_published, b.updated AS post_updated,
       b.content AS post_content, b.num_replies AS post_replies, 
       b.num_plus_ones AS post_plus_ones, b.num_reshares AS post_reshares,
       c.display_name AS attach_display_name, c.content AS attach_content,
       c.url AS attach_url, c.image_url AS attach_image,
       c.image_width AS attach_width, c.image_height AS attach_height,
       c.full_image_url AS attach_full_image
  FROM cr_google_profiles a
  JOIN cr_google_posts b
  LEFT JOIN cr_google_post_attachements c 
    ON b.post_id = c.post_id
 WHERE a.google_id = :google_id AND b.google_id = :google_id AND c.google_id = :google_id
```

I'm really lost on how to do this; I've been YouTubing and reading the manual but haven't come up with anything that would accomplish what I'm looking for. Any help or constructive criticism is more than welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a way to correctly `JOIN` your tables? Something like this

```
SELECT ...
  FROM cr_google_profiles a JOIN cr_google_posts b 
    ON a.google_id = b.google_id LEFT JOIN cr_google_post_attachements c 
    ON b.google_id = c.google_id AND b.post_id = c.post_id 
WHERE a.google_id = :google_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you've not specified a join condition for the join of `a` and `b`, so you really need something like:

```
SELECT a.display_name, a.first_name, a.last_name, a.profile_image, a.tagline,
       a.bragging_rights, a.about_me, b.type AS post_type, b.title AS post_title,
       b.published AS post_published, b.updated AS post_updated,
       b.content AS post_content, b.num_replies AS post_replies, 
       b.num_plus_ones AS post_plus_ones, b.num_reshares AS post_reshares,
       c.display_name AS attach_display_name, c.content AS attach_content,
       c.url AS attach_url, c.image_url AS attach_image,
       c.image_width AS attach_width, c.image_height AS attach_height,
       c.full_image_url AS attach_full_image
  FROM cr_google_profiles a
  JOIN cr_google_posts b
    ON a.google_id = b.google_id
  LEFT JOIN cr_google_post_attachements c 
    ON b.post_id = c.post_id
 WHERE a.google_id = :google_id
   AND b.google_id = :google_id
   AND c.google_id = :google_id
```